# when given voltage, reverse voltage according to scale

Tags: voltage, dc

I am given a DC line with a variable voltage along a set scale: let's say 0-10V. I would like to send an output DC line with a voltage reversed along that scale.
For example:

- 10 Volts in becomes 0 Volts out,
- 9 Volts in becomes 1 Volt out,
- 5 Volts in becomes 5 Volts out,
- 0 Volts in becomes 10 Volts out.

Note that the polarity is not reversed.

My question is: is there device I can buy or a relatively simple wiring scheme that can get me there? My intention is to take a signal from a PID tension-controller that controls a brake, and instead power a motor when needed. Oof, good question on the current. Let's say it is one amp.

Comment: 1) If you want an answer, ask a question. 2) Need more context; What exactly are you trying to achieve, and what for?

Comment: Also mention how much current is needed. 0-10V is a standard control voltage for LED dimmers so are we talking about that?

Comment: I guess OP wants us to design a circuit for that. That's not what we do here. **You** can propose a circuit and we can comment on that and suggest improvements. But since you have no experience with electronics all I can tell you is: forget this. If this needs to be done get someone **with** experience in electronics. There are simply hundreds of things you would need to know even if we gave you a circuit design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the voltage just for indication or measurement then a simple DC differential amplifier with unity gain will do the job, because the output voltage is 10V minus input voltage: \$V_{out} = 10V - V_{in}\$.
:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEoLoH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that this circuit is not easy to build as it looks even for an experienced person because of the need of a negative supply (-12V). Also, generating the reference voltage ("10V" to the left-side leg on R2) can be problematic *(e.g. voltage divider or from an outer generator)*.

Comment: Hi Rohat! Thanks for the answer! I'm having difficulty running the simulation for that circuit, but it if it as described, I think we can do it.